# HAML Syntax error on form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

My field_for is throwing a syntax error i dont know why?  How am i suppose to indent this?

```
Inconsistent indentation: "\t  " used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 1 tab.

= form_for(:contacts, url: contacts_path) do |f|
  = f.error_messages
  = f.label :subject, "Name"
  %span{style: 'color: red'} *
  = f.text_field :subject, class: "text_field width_100_percent"
  %br
  %br    
  = f.label "Email"
  %span{style: 'color: red'} *
  %br    
  = f.email_field :email, class: "text_field width_100_percent"
  %br
  %br
  = f.label "Phone"
  %br    
  = f.fields_for :custom_field do |cust|
    = cust.text_field :phone_number_28445
  %br
  %br
  = f.label "Question(s), and/or feedback"
  %span{style: 'color: red'} *
  %br
  = f.text_area :description, class: "text_field width_100_percent", style: 'height: 100px;'
  %br
  %br
  = f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-warning'
```

I know its my field_for because as soon as i take it out the form works again

Answer (score 1):

I've dealt with this before. It can be a pain. Usually happens if you've copied and pasted code from another IDE then modify part of the file.

As the error says, you've indented that line with a tab, plus two spaces whereas the rest of the file is indented just with just tabs. Some IDEs will insert two spaces when you enter a tab instead of actually inserting a tab. Check your editor's settings, or replace the indentation on the other lines such that everything is indented with 2 spaces replacing each tab.

Answer (score 1):

if you are defining any field in side a span use one tab like
%span{style: 'color: red'} *
  = f.text_field :subject, class: "text_field width_100_percent"
i guess it will be helpful and try to use any ide to format your code because it seems like a code formatting and indentation problem